# SPFx: pnp.sp.search what is Refiners and how them to use?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, spfx, spfx-webparts, pnp

I making simple SPFx search. I need to use Refiners to get data from SharePoint. Which Refiners is available to use? Can you please give me example with Refiners?

```
pnp.sp.search({ Querytext: queryText, SelectProperties: selectProperties, EnableSorting: true, Refiners: ["DisplayAuthor"], SortList:sorts });
```

Comment: Here is a document for reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/query-refinement-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add Refiners in string format like:

```
{
  'Querytext': 'sharepoint',
  'Refiners': 'author,size',
}
```

**Documentation**: [SharePoint Search REST API overview - Refiners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#refiners)

---

Also, check this issue on GitHub for more information: [pnp.sp.search does not work with Refiners set](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/241)

Comment: @GaneshSnap, how to get refiners by my managed propertie RefinersTextListOWSTEXT?
I tried `'Refiners': 'RefinersTextListOWSTEXT'` but it doesn't work